# How do I share a friend's post on my wall, using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I share a friend's post on my wall? I don't want to copy the original post's text and create a new post, becuase I need my friend to see that I shared his post.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Graph API doesn't provides anything to share posts. However you can perform a 'comment' or 'like'.